# How do I test long session timeouts in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

Lets say I set the session timeout to 2 days, how would I test this? How can I be sure that this happens? Anyway to simulate this or make sure that this happens without actually waiting for 2 days?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use session for the long time period.. use persistent cookies for it.